# How to use a specific keyboard layout upon boot?

Tags: keyboard, catalina, startup, nvram, dvorak

I've installed [DosDude's patches](http://dosdude1.com/catalina/) to get Catalina running on my Mac Pro 4,1.

However, I'm a Dvorak typist, and now I find I'm booting Catalina in "Canadian English" layout instead of Dvorak. So I have to struggle to type in my password! After I log in, I do have the Dvorak layout.

I thought this was in NVRAM, but the only interesting output from "nvram -p" is "prev-lang:kbd" which is set to "en:16300", which is [exactly what you'd want for Dvorak](https://github.com/acidanthera/OpenCorePkg/blob/master/Utilities/AppleKeyboardLayouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.txt).

So, how can I boot Catalina and have it come up in Dvorak layout?

Comment: does this help? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202036

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I'd done all those things. I finally got it to work by accident, but doing 'sudo nvram boot-args="-no_compat_check -v"' made it work… don't know why…